# Possibility to get raw gps data from device

Tags: html, gps

The title says everything :)

I'm developing a web application and would love to have all the data (especially the heading, number of satellites and speed) from a mobile device.

Through this code it's easy to get the lat/lon pair:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  alert("Your lat/lng pair is" + position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude);
});
```

Is there a way to get the other data with HTML5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of other bits of data you can obtain through the W3C Geolocation API, and they're listed in a table in this article: [Finding your position with Geolocation - HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/). Only some of them are guaranteed to be there, but the article should tell you all you need to know.